# RawByteString type in Free Pascal

Tags: delphi, fpc, rawbytestring

[Free Pascal docs](http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_Unicode_support#RawByteString) state that `RawByteString` type is defined in Free Pascal but I cannot find where. One should expect that it is defined in `System` unit, like in Delphi, but when I compile (using FPC 2.6.2, {$mode delphi}) a function declaration

```
class function FromAnsi(const S: RawByteString): ByteArray; static;
```

I get the compiler error

```
Error: Identifier not found "RawByteString"
```

Guess I can declare the type myself:

```
type
  RawByteString = type AnsiString(CP_NONE);
```

but I would like to find the "native" FPC declaration.

---

Thanks for quick answers. Since I don't need to support FPC 1.x the workaround I need is:

```
{$IFDEF FPC}
{$IF FPC_VERSION = 2}
  {$IF FPC_RELEASE <= 6}
    type
      RawByteString = AnsiString;
  {$IFEND}
{$IFEND}
{$ENDIF}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use FPC 2.7.1.

The new string types do not exist in 2.6.x

Comment: I don't know about `RawByteString`, but `UnicodeString` has been available in FPC since at least 2.4.0, and FPC has `unicodestrings` and `delphiunicode` modes, and a `FPC_UNICODESTRINGS` define, to control/detect whether `string` maps to `AnsiString` or `UnicodeString`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: With "new string types" I refer to the  strings with dynamical encoding, vs.  `UnicodeString/WideString/AnsiString` with the statical encoding...  (Although someone could already consider `AnsiString` a new string type, compared to `shortstring`)

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://wiki.freepascal.org/FPC_Unicode_support#RawByteString) that you linked in the question:

> Up to and including FPC 2.6.x, the RTL was based on the ones of Turbo
>   Pascal and Delphi 7. This means it was primarily based around the
>   shortstring, ansistring and pchar types. None of these types had any
>   encoding information associated with them, but were implicitly assumed
>   to be encoded in the "default system encoding" and were passed on to
>   OS API calls without any conversion.
>
> In Delphi 2009, Embarcadero switched the entire RTL over to the
>   UnicodeString type, which represents strings using UTF-16.
>   Additionally, they also made the AnsiString type "code page-aware".
>   This means that AnsiStrings from then on contain the code page
>   according to which their data should be interpreted.
>
> FPC's language-level support for these string types is already
>   available in current development versions of the compiler (FPC
>   2.7.1/trunk). The RTL level support is not yet complete. This page gives an overview of the code page-related behaviour of these string
>   types, the current level of support in the RTL, and possible future
>   ways of how this support may be improved.

In other words, you need at least 2.7 for the new D2009 alike string types.